# How to Change the Default Azure RM subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

ASM had the ability to change the default subscription with the -Default (and now deprecated) parameter

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default
```

but the ARM version

```
Select-AzureRMSubscription
```

does not have the -Default parameter.

How can I change the default ARM subscription? It is very annoying that my default is a subscription that I never use.

**Edit for clarification**: When I say change default subscription I mean the default subscription that you are connected to with each new PowerShell session.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Comment: @Bruce I have not had time to test your answer yet but am pretty sure it does not change the Default subscription......such that next time I log in the subscription change was not persisted.

Comment: resolved as of Azure PowerShell version 5 see answer below.

Comment: Thankfully, I don't have to mess with Azure 'mess' any longer so I can't validate an answer.

Answer (score 38):

Step 1: **Get-AzureRmSubscription**

It will List all your subscriptions.

Step 2: **Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx**

The SubscriptionID can be found in the output of the Get-AzureRmSubscription. You can also use the SubscriptionName.

Step 3: **(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription**

Confirm that you have selected the right subscription.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there is a way, but for me I've added the following to my [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) profile:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName "My Subscription"
```

How to customize PowerShell [profile](http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

Answer (score 7):

According to your requirement, I tested the following command to change my subscription on my side and I could change the subscription.

`Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "your subscription" | Select-AzureRmSubscription`

Here is my test, you could refer to it.

[image]

**Note:** You could find the command in this official [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx) about Azure Resource Manager Cmdlets.

Comment: This only changes the subscription for the current 'session'. If you quit PowerShell and comeback the Default subscription has not changed.

Answer (score 6):

This is now resolved with Azure PowerShell version 5.

```
Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave
```

Once you run this command, every new Azure PowerShell session will default to the last context set with the

```
Set-AzureRMContext
```

command

Answer (score 2):

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -Environment [If Needed] -Subscription "[Add Yours]" -ContextName "Default"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same challenge - there does not seem to be any Cmdlet in the `AzureRM` module for it `[version 4.2.0]`:

```
Get-Command set-*subscription* -Module AzureRM
```

Subscription objects returned by Get-AzureSubscription (Azure module) are obviously different from those returned by the GetAzureRmSubscription - ie there's not a *IsDefault* property on the ARM-ones.

Following the mindset of `4c74356b41` you could add a less "disturbing" line in your profile:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues["Login-AzureRmAccount:SubscriptionName"] = "my subscriptionName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two scenarios not covered is if you already have a PowerShell profile that you want to edit and if you want to change the PowerShell profile for PowerShell ISE.

The easiest way to set your subscription in ARM is to use your PowerShell profile as [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) points out.

To find the path to your PowerShell profiles use `$Profile | Format-List`.

The Windows PowerShell profile is typically in ..\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

The PowerShell ISE profile is typically in ..\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

If either are missing use `New-Item -path $profile -type file –force` from the ISE or PowerShell window to create an empty file.

If you want to list all PowerShell profile files with their path add the -Force switch `$Profile | Format-List -Force`.

If you are using a Microsoft account, such as me@outlook.com, then add this to the .ps1 file `Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId "Tenant ID" -SubscriptionId "Subscription ID"`.  You can get a list of all Subscription and Tenant IDs using 
`Get-AzureRmSubscription | Format-List`.

You could use [APowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5773631/apowershell)'s answer also, I prefer not to use the Subscription Name parameter.  It isn't uncommon for the sub name to change when you have multiple subs, the SubID and TenantID will not change.

If you are logging in using a work account like user@domain.com then you can automate the entire login and subscription selection using something like this.

```
$AzureAcct = "user@contoso.com"
$AzurePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@s$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$AzureCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureAcct, $AzurePwd)

$Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCreds -TenantId "Tenant ID" -SubscriptionId "Subscription ID"
```

If you only use the parameter `-SubscriptionId` you can get login errors if the account has been added to multiple Azure subscriptions, so it is important to use `-TenantId` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You will hav eto use context like this `Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName` for every session